# PHP sort values with two table results

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to sort results using `ORDER BY DESC`, but results are being sorted by `foreach` values:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlgroup)){ 
    $member_array = $row["member_array"];

    if ($member_array !=""){
        $memberArray = explode(",", $member_array);
        $i = 0;
        $cashstatsList .= '
        ';
        foreach($memberArray as $gkey => $mvalue){
            $i++;

            $arraystats = "SELECT player.first_name, player.last_name, SUM(groupcash.grpcsh_earnings) AS memsum, AVG (groupcash.grpcsh_earnings) AS memavg,
                            SUM(groupcash.grpcsh_w) AS memcntpos, SUM(groupcash.grpcsh_l) AS memcntneg
                            FROM player, groupcash
                            WHERE (player.id = grpcsh_plrid) AND (player.id = $mvalue) AND (groupcash.grpcsh_groupid = $groupid)                                        
                            AND (grpcsh_date >= '$thisyr') AND (grpcsh_date <= '$today') ORDER BY SUM(groupcash.grpcsh_earnings) DESC                               
                            ";

             $arraystatsResutls = mysqli_query($link, $arraystats);
             if (!$arraystatsResutls){
                $cashstatsList .= '                         
                    <tr>
                        <td>                            
                            No results available for listed dates
                        </td>
                    </tr>';
            } else {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($arraystatsResutls)){ 
                    $memberFirstName = $row["first_name"]; 
                    $memberLastName = $row["last_name"];
                    $sum = $row["memsum"];
                    $avg = $row["memavg"];
                    $win = $row["memcntpos"];
                    $loss = $row["memcntneg"];

                    if ($memberFirstName == "" || $memberLastName == ""){
                        $sqlName = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM player WHERE id='$mvalue' LIMIT 1") or die ("Sorry we had a mysql error!");
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlName)) {
                                $memberFirstName = $row["first_name"]; $memberLastName = $row["last_name"];
                            }                                           
                    }

                    if ($sum == ""){
                        $sum = "0";
                    }
                    if ($avg == ""){
                        $avg = "0";
                    }
                    if ($win == ""){
                        $win = "0";
                    }
                    if ($loss == ""){
                        $loss = "0";
                    }

                    $cashstatsList .= '
                        <tr align="center">
                            <td>
                                ' . $i . '
                            </td>
                                <td>
                                ' . $memberFirstName . '&nbsp;' . $memberLastName . '
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                $' . $sum . '
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                $' . $avg . '
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                ' . $win . '/' . $loss . '
                            </td>
                        </tr>'; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the first query being looped

Answer (score 0):

You have to select all member of the group at once in the query so they can be "ORDER BY", here you have only results on the same member for each request so the order doesn't change anything in the order of result between member.

If `$member_array` is like `1,454,33,22` you can just remove the foreach and use the query :

```
$arraystats = "SELECT player.first_name, player.last_name, SUM(groupcash.grpcsh_earnings) AS memsum, AVG (groupcash.grpcsh_earnings) AS memavg,
                SUM(groupcash.grpcsh_w) AS memcntpos, SUM(groupcash.grpcsh_l) AS memcntneg
                FROM player, groupcash
                WHERE (player.id = grpcsh_plrid) AND (player.id IN ($member_array)) AND (groupcash.grpcsh_groupid = $groupid)                                        
                AND (grpcsh_date >= '$thisyr') AND (grpcsh_date <= '$today') ORDER BY SUM(groupcash.grpcsh_earnings) DESC                               
                ";
```

So you will get all the member of the group at the same time and the ORDER BY will work.